# QName for Triples (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, geospatial, marklogic

I have been attempting various ways to access the lat and long QName from my triples. An example of my triple data is

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
  <sem:triple>
    <sem:subject>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Slantsy</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object>http://www.opengis.net/gml/_Feature</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
  <sem:triple>
    <sem:subject>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Slantsy</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">59.11666666666667</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
  <sem:triple>
    <sem:subject>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Slantsy</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.083333333333332</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
  <sem:triple>
    <sem:subject>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Slantsy</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://www.georss.org/georss/point</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object xml:lang="en">59.11666666666667 28.083333333333332</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
</sem:triples>
```

Output from SPARQL "DESCRIBE"

```
@prefix xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix p2: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Slantsy> <http://www.georss.org/georss/point> "59.11666666666667 28.083333333333332"@en ;
                                      a <http://www.opengis.net/gml/_Feature> ;
                                      p2:long "28.0833333333333"^^xs:double ;
                                      p2:lat "59.1166666666667"^^xs:double .
```

I have seen a similar case in this thread [How to create and use GeoSpatial indexes in Marklogic from Sparql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296551/how-to-create-and-use-geospatial-indexes-in-marklogic-from-sparql)

where the Qname was accessed using

```
fn:QName("http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#", "lat")
```

Hence, I tried a similar approach and used

```
cts:search(/sem:triples,
   cts:element-pair-geospatial-query(
     xs:QName("sem:triples"),
     fn:QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/01/geo/wgs84_pos#", "lat"),
     fn:QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/01/geo/wgs84_pos#", "long"),
     cts:circle(2000, cts:point(59,28)))
)
```

However, I received an empty query which do not seem to be correct. Any advise would be greatly appreciated Thanks.

===Update===
Finally got it to work as suggested by grtjin. The geospatial index was added using the path

```
/sem:triples/sem:triple[sem:predicate = 'http://www.georss.org/georss/point']/sem:object
```

and queried using

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),
  cts:path-geospatial-query(
  "/sem:triples/sem:triple[sem:predicate = 'http://www.georss.org/georss/point']/sem:object",
  cts:circle(10, cts:point(59,28))
  )
)
```

Which works and returns the proper results.

However I also attempted to query using

```
cts:search(fn:doc()/sem:triples,
  cts:path-geospatial-query(
  "/sem:triple[sem:predicate = 'http://www.georss.org/georss/point']/sem:object",
  cts:circle(10, cts:point(59,28))
  )
)
```

Despite expecting this to work because I should be querying each sem:triples item using the path specified to reach a specific lat,long point. I received an empty query instead. Am I understanding something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice if you could do this, but the element-pair index doesn't work this way unfortunately.

Firstly, the child elements must be direct children of the indicated ancestor, which is why it speaks of parent rather than ancestor.

Secondly, you cannot target element values like that. The elements containing lat and long are both `sem:object` elements.

I'd suggest using a geospatial path index instead, on something that contains a point, and you happen to have that. This as path reference should work I think:

```
sem:triple[sem:predicate = "http://www.georss.org/georss/point"]/sem:object
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you I finally got it to work. However I have a small question I encountered, which can be found in my updated post, I hope you can have a quick look at it. @grtjin

Comment: Make sure your expression in your path index matches what you pass in into the path-query. Next, keep in mind that path starting with `/` are considered absolute paths (starting at the top of documents). Consider leaving off `/sem:triples/`, and just start with `sem:triple`. That way it will match sem:triple elements anywhere in documents..